# The file you are trying to open is in a different format then specified by the file extension

Tags: c#, excel, csv, file-format

C# error when attempting to open a csv file in excel. The file you are trying to open is in a different format than specified by the file extension.

Here's the code:

```
private void BtnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] data = rtbConvData.Text.Split('\n');

    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Filter = "CSV (Comma delimited)(*.csv)|*.csv";
    //sfd.FileName = "Data Conversion " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy");
    sfd.FileName = lblFileName.Text;

    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        xlexcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
        Workbook xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        for (int i = 1; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = data[i - 1];
        }

        // Save the excel file under the captured location from the SaveFileDialog
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlexcel.DisplayAlerts = true;
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlexcel.Quit();

        ReleaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        ReleaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        ReleaseObject(xlexcel);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're saving it as a CSV but making an XLSX file. If you need a CSV, then do that, and don't use Excel for it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat - xlCSV

Comment: **Excel's native format is not CSV!** If you put a csv extension on a file saved normally by Excel, it's gonna confuse most software, including Excel.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn your code is saving an Excel file as *Excel* ( XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal) with the wrong extension. This code makes little sense. Why use Excel at all if you want to save a CSV file? A CSV is a plain old text file with no sheets, cells etc. You can easily write comma-separated values to a text file or use a library like CsvHelper to handle escaping if necessary

Comment: On the other hand if you want to create an Excel file *don't* save it with the `.csv` extension. You don't need Excel to create Excel files either, you can use libraries like Epplus or ClosedXML

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: apparently this error can occur when the first two characters of the csv file are "ID", see [wikipedia:SYLK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_Link_(SYLK)) for the full details.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a file of [Comma-Separated Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (CSV) extension, then the format of the file has some expected rules, that are roughly as follows:

- each line represents a row
- rows are separated by a [delimiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter)/separator
- the values separated by delimiters represent cells in the row

When a csv file is attempted to be parsed, then such rules are assumed to exist. Whatever technology is responsible to parse such a file, either has a validator which checks whether "the file looks good", or assumes that it does. If the file does not comply to the expectations, then it is expectable to get an error. So, you should convert your file into csv somehow if possible. If not, then detect what the file format is and parse it with the appropriate parser.